# iOS - Displaying Two Words At A Time From String Array

Tags: ios, arrays, nsstring

I'm doing an RSVP reading project app where it blinks words on the screen. You can set the word chunk size (how many words you want displayed at a time) to either 1, 2, or 3. I got it working for 1 word by having my paragraph in a string and doing:

`[self.textInput componentsSeparatedByString:@" ";`

This makes me an array of words that I can use to blink one word at a time. How would I be able to do this with displaying 2 words at a time? Is there a way I can use this function again to do it differently, or should I iterate over this word array and make a new one with 2 word strings?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated as to what the best practice would to get this done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like keith said create an array

```
NSArray *allwordsArray = [self.textInput componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Now you got all the info you need. Meaning you got the array with every word in it. Now its just a matter of putting it together. (I haven't tested this code)

```
    NSMutableArray *twoWordArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int counter=0;
    for (int i=0; i<[allwordsArray count]; i++)
    {
       if (counter >= [allwordsArray count]) break;
       NSString *str1 =  [NSString stringwithformat@"%@", [allwordsArray objectAtIndex:counter]];

       counter++;

         if (counter >= [allwordsArray count]) break;
         NSString *str2 =  [NSString stringwithformat@"%@", [allwordsArray objectAtIndex:counter]];
         NSString *combinedStr = [NSString stringwithformat@"%@ %@", str1,str2];
         [twoWordArray addObject: combinedStr];

         counter++;

    }
```

Comment: This solution worked great! Using an extra counter stopped all the confusion I had, thanks! :)

Comment: glad I could help :-). It was definitely an interesting problem

Answer (score 0):

You have broken the string into components, which is on the right track. You could then make a smaller array that only includes components until you reach the chunk size. The final step would be to rejoin the string.

```
NSArray *components = [self.textInput componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSRange chunkRange = NSMakeRange(0, chunkSize);
NSArray *lessComponents = [components subarrayWithRange:chunkRange];
NSString *newString = [lessComponents componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```